# Waiting for profiling to be done

Tags: r

I'm trying to fit my data in order to use the `R0` package. So I tried to run the example as it is specified in the R documentation for **estimate.R {R0}** (Estimate R0 for one incidence dataset using several methods).

However when I run the example data I get:
Waiting for profiling to be done...

So I can't get the original example to work.

```
data(Germany.1918)
mGT<-generation.time("gamma", c(3, 1.5))
estR0<-estimate.R(Germany.1918, mGT, begin=1, end=27, methods=c("EG", "ML", "TD", "AR", "SB"), 
                  pop.size=100000, nsim=100)
```

If anyone can run the example and try to replicate my error message, I'd appreciate some insights.

Comment: That isn't an error. In addition to the message you show I see two warnings which are quite informative.

Comment: Thank you @Roland May, could you please share more information? Thanks!

Comment: Any help or comment will be welcomed.